# Magic number with MmMapIoSpace

Tags: windows, memory-management, driver, kernel

So upon mapping a memory space with `MmMapIoSpace`, I noticed that past a certain point, the data was just being discarded when written to. No errors, breakpoints, or even bugchecks were thrown. Everything worked as normal, just without any adverse effects.

I decided to do a write/read test (the driver would write 1's to every byte for the length of the *intended* size) and the reader (userland) mode would read and report where the 1's ended.

The number it came up with was 3208, which is a seemingly nice, round number (/8=401, /256=12, etc.)

What's up with this? How come I can't map the full buffer space?

**EDIT** And in 64-bit it drops to 2492.

Comment: MmMapIoSpace is intended for accessing memory-mapped I/O devices.  How the memory behaves presumably depends on the hardware device in question.  Conversely, if you're pointing it at physical RAM rather than an I/O device, you're using it in an unsupported way and the behaviour is presumably undefined.  If this doesn't answer your question, you need to provide us with more context: for example, what sort of device is your device driver managing?

Comment: It's mapping memory from to the user-land driver

Comment: Wow I just realized I made a derp comment. It maps User-land memory to a driver-writeable buffer.

Comment: Based on the documentation for MmMapIoSpace, I'm pretty sure it doesn't support what you're trying to do.  Did you want your driver to access a memory buffer allocated by a user-space process, or were you trying to give a user-space process access to a buffer allocated by the driver?

Comment: Is PhysicalAddress (as passed to MmMapIoSpace) page-aligned?  I don't see how the mapping could stop working anywhere but at the end of a page, so I'm guessing that the 3208/2492 you're seeing is determined entirely by the offset of PhysicalAddress within its page.  (Pages are 4096 bytes on x86 and x64 systems, or 8192 on IA64.)

Comment: I need the driver to access the buffer allocated by the user-space. It works just fine, it just seems to have this weird limitation. This is exactly how it's documented all over the web.

Comment: where is this behaviour of [MMMapIoSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554618(v=vs.85).aspx) documented? mapping of user-mode buffers to kernel mode is usually done via IOCTL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I don't see how MmMapIoSpace can be relied upon to do what you're asking it to, because there's no guarantee that the user-space buffer is contiguous in physical memory.

Instead, I think you should be using [`IoAllocateMdl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`MmProbeAndLockPages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to lock down the user buffer and then [`MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to map it into the system address space.  This process is [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463199.aspx).

As previous stated, I think that the point at which the mapping is failing (3208/2492 bytes into the buffer) is probably just the end of the page, but that's easy enough for you to verify: get the user-space application to report the (virtual) address of the first byte that didn't get written rather than the offset, and check whether it is a multiple of 4096 or not.

Comment: Yep it is (40400/9). Interesting! I'll play around with your method to see if I can't do such a thing.

Comment: Not to throw a spanner in the works, but 40400 isn't a multiple of 4096.  (Note that the Windows calculator, when in programming mode, truncates the fractional part when you do division.)