# Two-way communication between kernel-mode driver and user-mode application?

Tags: windows, driver, interrupt, wfp, windows-kernel

I need a two-way communication between a kernel-mode WFP driver and a user-mode application. The driver initiates the communication by passing a URL to the application which then does a categorization of that URL (Entertainment, News, Adult, etc.) and passes that category back to the driver. The driver needs to know the category in the filter function because it may block certain web pages based on that information. I had a thread in the application that was making an I/O request that the driver would complete with the URL and a GUID, and then the application would write the category into the registry under that GUID where the driver would pick it up. Unfortunately, as the driver verifier pointed out, this is unstable because the Zw registry functions have to run at PASSIVE_LEVEL. I was thinking about trying the same thing with mapped memory buffers, but I’m not sure what the interrupt requirements are for that. Also, I thought about lowering the interrupt level before the registry function calls, but I don't know what the side effects of that are.

Comment: You're already using conventional I/O from the driver to the application to pass the URLs; why not use conventional I/O to return the result as well?

Comment: Because the request initiates from the driver, I couldn't figure out how to make it work. The app makes an I/O request, the driver completes it with the URL in the output buffer, then how does the app get information back to the driver since the I/O request is complete? Also, the operation is time-sensitive because I'm making a decision about whether to block a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have two different kinds of I/O request.

If you're using [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the URLs (I think this would be the most suitable method) this is as simple as adding a second I/O control code.

If you're using `ReadFile` or equivalent, things would normally get a bit messier, but as it happens in this specific case you only have two kinds of operations, one of which is a read (driver->application) and the other of which is a write (application->driver).  So you could just use `WriteFile` to send the reply, including of course the GUID so that the driver can match up your reply to the right query.

Another approach (more similar to your original one) would be to use a shared memory buffer.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047456/886887) for more details.  The problem with that idea is that you would either need to use a spinlock (at the cost of system performance and power consumption, and of course not being able to work on a single-core system) or to poll (which is both inefficient and not really suitable for time-sensitive operations).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing unstable about PASSIVE_LEVEL. Access to registry must be at PASSIVE_LEVEL so it's not possible directly if driver is running at higher IRQL. You can do it by offloading to work item, though. Lowering the IRQL is usually not recommended as it contradicts the OS intentions.

Your protocol indeed sounds somewhat cumbersome and doing a direct app-driver communication is probably preferable. You can find useful information about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554436(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I could have phrased that better. It's "unstable" in the sense that it doesn't crash every time, but the WFP filter functions run at DISPATCH_LEVEL so the registry functions are inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Since the callouts are at DISPATCH, your processing has to be done either in a worker thread or a DPC, which will allow you to use ZwXXX. You should into inverted callbacks for communication purposes, there's a good document on OSR.

I've just started poking around WFP but it looks like even in the samples that they provide, Microsoft reinject the packets. I haven't looked into it that closely but it seems that they drop the packet and re-inject whenever processed. That would be enough for your use mode engine to make the decision. You should also limit the packet capture to a specific port (80 in your case) so that you don't do extra processing that you don't need.