# Shared memory between kernel and user mode. How to share handle?

Tags: c++, windows, kernel

I am trying to use shared memory between user process and kernel.

Option one - to let kernel to create section and let user mode app to open memory by name "Global\my_mem". It's working only in read-only mode. When I am trying to open section with FILE_MAP_WRITE it gives access denied(5). Not sure how to grant access or modify DACL.

Option two - pass handle back via IOCTL. This one is questionable since handle to section opened in KERNEL is 0xFFFFFFFF80001234. My understanding that handles that have any of upper bits set can not be used in user mode. Especially if app will be 32-bit :) Initially I expected that section handle will be somewhat similar to kernel file handle and I will be able to use it.

What would be the correct approach to establish shared memory channel between kernel and user mode?

Comment: Microsoft published [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/KM-UMGuide.doc "this") document, which describes option #1 in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For option 1, you can specify the security descriptor assigned to the newly created object via the `SecurityDescriptor` member of the [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For option 2, you would need to create an additional handle as a user handle, which you do by not specifying the `OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE` flag in the `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` structure.  This will only work if you open the new handle while running in the context of a thread belonging to the user application's process, e.g., while processing an IOCTL received from the user application.

Another option is for the kernel driver to map the section into the user-mode application's address space itself, using [ZwMapViewOfSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

One issue with using a section is that the driver itself can only safely access it from a system thread.  If that is a problem, you can share memory directly rather than via a section.  If you allocate the memory in kernel mode, you can map it into the user-mode application's address space using [MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Yet another option is for [the driver to access a memory buffer allocated by the user-mode process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047456/886887).

The downside to either of these approaches is that the buffer (or the part of it being shared) must be locked in memory, whereas using a section allows the buffer to be pageable.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. Just tried to create handle (no OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE) while processing IOCTL_MINIPORT_PROCESS_SERVICE_IRP, but do mapping of a  section view later in a context of system thread. Didn't work. Handle not accepted.

Comment: can you please specify (if possible) how to allocate memory and map it to system process and at the same time while in context of user process to map it there?

Comment: You can't use a single handle for both the user process and the system thread.  I'll edit to clarify.  As for allocating the memory in the driver and then mapping it into the user-mode application's address space, I don't have the details to hand, but the documentation for MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache specifically says that having both a user-mode and system-mode mapping at the same time is not a problem.  However, if you are using a system thread anyway, using a section is preferable, because it is simpler and because it allows memory paging.

Comment: Thanks. It works. In a context of non-admin user process pend irp, create section, save handle1. In context of system thread open section by name, create handle2 and map view, complete irp and send handle1 back. In user process use handle1 and do another mapping. But at same time I found that it is not recommended way and need to use DeviceIO IOCTL IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT for storport miniport driver. Answered!

Answer (score 0):

Since you referred to 32bit app, I assume it is between a user process and a device driver  - I would go with  IOCTL - `METHOD_IN_DIRECT` (receives data in the buffer) and `METHOD_OUT_DIRECT` (write data into the buffer).

If shared memory is between multiple user processes and one or more device drivers - using shared Memory Object method is recommended .